# Why do the Python elementTree & bs4 libraries fail here?

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup, elementtree

I have a problem using bs4 and elementTree to extract data from a simple xml file. From the error message, the problem could be in the XML file or in the code.

**xml document:**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='yes' ?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="sms.xsl"?>
<smses count=54 backup_date="" type="full">
  <sms protocol="70" address="+722000000" contact_name="null" date="1533463848058" readable_date="Aug 05, 20111 " type="1" subject="null" body="I tried to call you at 13:05 on 05 Aug Please call back. Dial *444*2# to call for 2 bob per minute across all networks" toa="null" sc_toa="null" service_center="+254722500041" read="1" status="-1" locked="0" />
  <sms protocol="0" address="Google" contact_name="null" date="1533464034291" readable_date="Aug 05, 2043 " type="1" subject="null" body="G-2323 is your Google verification code." toa="null" sc_toa="null" service_center="+320335320086" read="1" status="-1" locked="0" />
  <sms protocol="0" address="Google" contact_name="null" date="1533463862102" readable_date="Aug 05, 2018 " type="1" subject="null" body="G-2323 is your Google verification code." toa="null" sc_toa="null" service_center="+46731210314" read="1" status="-1" locked="0" />
  <sms protocol="0" address="Google" contact_name="null" date="1533463856825" readable_date="Aug 05, 2018 " type="1" subject="null" body="G-2323 is your Google verification code." toa="null" sc_toa="null" service_center="+46731210314" read="1" status="-1" locked="0" />
  <sms protocol="0" address="Google" contact_name="null" date="1533463851975" readable_date="Aug 05, 2018 " type="1" subject="null" body="G-32434 is your Google verification code." toa="null" sc_toa="null" service_center="+46731210314" read="1" status="-1" locked="0" />
 </smses>
```

**b​s4 attempt:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with open('backup.xml', 'r') as f:
    data = f.read()

bsdata = BeautifulSoup(data, 'xml')

allsms = bsdata.findall('smses/sms')
print('how many?:', len(allsms))

protocol_list = []
address_list = []
contact_name_list = []
date_list = []
readable_date_list = []
type_list = []
subject_list = []
body_list = []
toa_list = []
sc_toa_list = []
service_center_list  = []
read_list = []
status_list = []
locked_list = []

for sms in allsms:
    protocol_list.append(sms.get("protocol"))
    address_list.append(sms.get("address"))
    contact_name_list.append(sms.get("contact_name"))
    date_list.append(sms.get("date"))
    readable_date_list.append(sms.get("readable_date"))
    type_list.append(sms.get("type"))
    subject_list.append(sms.get("subject"))
    body_list.append(sms.get("body"))
    toa_list.append(sms.get("toa"))
    sc_toa_list.append(sms.get("sc_toa"))
    service_center_list.append(sms.get("service_center"))
    read_list.append(sms.get("read"))
    status_list.append(sms.get("status"))
    locked_list.append(sms.get("locked"))


print ("confirm lengths of the lists")
print("list \t\t\t\t length")
print("protocol_list \t\t\t\t ", len(protocol_list))
print("address_list \t\t\t\t", len(address_list))
print("contact_name_list \t\t\t\t", len(contact_name_list))
print("date_list \t\t\t\t", len(date_list))
print("readable_date_list \t\t\t\t", len(readable_date_list))
print("type_list \t\t\t\t", len(type_list))
print("subject_list \t\t\t\t", len(subject_list))
print("body_list\t\t\t\t", len(body_list))
print("toa_list \t\t\t\t", len(toa_list))
print("sc_toa_list \t\t\t\t", len(sc_toa_list))
print("service_center_list  is ", len(service_center_list))
print("read_list \t\t\t\t", len(read_list))
print("status_list \t\t\t\t", len(status_list))
print("locked_list \t\t\t\t ", len(locked_list))
```

E​RROR:

> File "", line unknown
> ParseError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 3, column 13

**e​lementTree attempt:**

```
# importing element tree
# under the alias of ET
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
 
# Passing the path of the
# xml document to enable the
# parsing process
tree = ET.parse('sample.xml')
 
# getting the parent tag of
# the xml document
root = tree.getroot()
 
# printing the root (parent) tag
# of the xml document, along with
# its memory location
print(root)
 
# printing the attributes of the
# first tag from the parent
print(root[0].attrib)
 
# printing the text contained within
# first subtag of the 5th tag from
# the parent
print(root[5][0].text)
```

E​RROR:

> File "", line unknown
> ParseError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 3, column 13

Comment: `count=54` is bad. It should be `count="54"`. Attribute values must be quoted.

Comment: As the error message says: on line 3 / column 13 there is `count=45`, should be `count="45"`